# Xamarin.Forms Application State and Push Notifcation

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification

Trying to understand what's going on here.

Here's what's going on.

The application starts normally,

1. registers all dependency services
2. register/subscribe push notification events from Plugin.FirebasePushNotification library

Now when I receive a push notification and tap on the notification box. The app re-launches again and repeats the flow above, but now the problem comes in #2 where I subscribed to the "event"s because now it's triggering twice.

Got a push notification, I tap on it, it's now triggering 3x, 4x, 5x and so on..

One specific event I use is the OnNotificationOpened. That triggers when I tap on the notification box and it will open a specific page. Right now, what's going on is, after tapping on the notification box for the 3rd time for example, it will launch that page 3x as well so when I press the back button, I get back to the same page 2x.

How do you prevent these? How to tell the app that it's already running, so please do not re-register all the services that has been registerd and re-subscribe to the events that has already been subscribed to?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, you could share some code about where*registers all dependency services*. You could save a flag in local device and detect its value to determine whether need to register again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Xamarin.Essentials: Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?tabs=android) to save a `flag` in local site to check whether need to register again.

For example, you could add following code around where registering all dependency services:

```
var myValue = Preferences.Get("register_success_key", "");
if (myValue == null)
{
   //registers all dependency services
   Preferences.Set("register_success_key", "value");
}
```